# Two errors for Nextjs: res.json is not a function and getserversideprops did not return an object

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm trying to make an api request and I do get the data because I tried console logging it and it shows on the console but I still get errors. Here are the errors:

```
TypeError: res.json is not a function

Error: Your `getServerSideProps` function did not return an object. Did you forget to add a `return`?
```

Here is my code:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  // API KEYS
  const apiKeyLocationIQ = process.env.API_KEY_LOCATIONIQ;
  const apiKeyWeather = process.env.API_KEY_WEATHER;
  // API REQUEST OPTIONS
  let cityLocationIQ = context.params.location;
  let urlLocationIQ = "https://api.locationiq.com/v1/search.php?format=JSON&key="+apiKeyLocationIQ+"&q="+cityLocationIQ+"&limit=1";
  // API REQUEST FOR LAT AND LON
  try{
    const res = await axios.get(urlLocationIQ).then((resLocation)=>{
      return resLocation
    })
    const weather = await res.json();
    return {
      props: {
        weather
      }
    }
  }catch (error){
    console.log( error);
  }
  
}
```

**UPDATE**
I made some changes to the axios request and I get a different error. This time it says:

```
function cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.
```

here is how my updated axios request looks like:

```
try{
    const res = await axios.get(urlLocationIQ, {responseType: 'json'})
    const weather = await res;
    return {
      props: {
        weather
      }
    }
  }catch (error){
    console.log( error);
    throw error;
  }
```

**FINAL UPDATE**
So it turns out that the axios request that I sent returns the entire request data including the headers etc. and the data that I needed was an object at the very bottom of the response, so all I had to do was to specify the data I needed.
Here is my code:

```
const location = await axios.get(urlLocationIQ).then((resLocation)=>{
      return {resLocation.data[0]}
    })
```

After that, the code works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, the value that `axios.get()` resolves to does not have a `.json()` method so thus the error you get.

You can tell Axios, ahead of time that you want it to parse a JSON response for you automatically.

```
const weather = (await axios.get(urlLocationIQ, {responseType: 'json'})).data;
```

But, that responseType is the default, so you can actually just do this assuming your response actually returns JSON:

```
const weather = (await axios.get(urlLocationIQ)).data;
```

I would assume you were perhaps expecting a `.json()` method like the `fetch()` interface uses, but that is not required with `axios`.  By default axios reads the response body for you whereas the `fetch()` interface does not read the response body (other than the headers) until you specifically call a method such as `.json()`.  But, that's not how axios works.  In this regard, axios often requires less lines of code to make a request and get the response.

---

P.S. Note that the `.then()` here:

```
.then((resLocation)=>{
  return resLocation
})
```

is pointless.  The promise already resolves to that value so adding a `.then()` that just returns it again is of no use.

---

Also, note that `getServerSideProps()` is an `async` function.  That means that it ALWAYS returns a promise and the resolved value of that promise will be whatever value you `return` from inside your function.  The caller of that function needs to either use `await` or `.then()` to get the resolved value.

---

And, in your `catch()`, you need to rethrow the error so that the caller gets the error.  Otherwise, you will just be eating the error and resolving the promise with `undefined` since there will be no return value.

```
} catch (error) {
    console.log( error);
    throw error;
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your help but now it is sending me another error. Here it is: 
`function cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.`

Comment: @CloydAbad - Where is that error coming from?  Please show me the EXACT code that leads to that error and show me the line of code that outputs that error.  I'm asking because it does not appear to be in the code you've disclosed so far.  To show me more code, use the "edit" link below your question and add the additional code AFTER what you already have there.  Do not remove what you already have as that needs to stay there to represent the original question.

Comment: @CloydAbad - First, where does this error message come from.  What line of code?  Second, when you do `console.log(weather)`, what do you see?

Comment: Hello! I figured it out, thanks to your answer, I tried to check what I was really getting after the request so I console logged the data. The data that I get had so many stuff that I couldnt understand, it was like the entire request was sent, including the headers. I saw at the very bottom an object that contained the data I needed. so I just had to specifiy what to return in the axios request.

Comment: @CloydAbad - Ahhh, yes Axios puts the actual data it read into `response.data`.  I updated my answer to show that too.